# PIC12F508 "Calibration value is invalid"

Tags: pic

We use PIC12F508 chips by the tens of thousands.  We normally purchase from people like Future Electronics or Arrow.  However, I see that our purchasing people are now buying 12F508 chips from someone whom I am not familiar with: Technoshack in Ontario, Canada.

Most of the places where we use this PIC controller do not have stringent timing requirements.  The native accuracy of the internal RC oscillator is entirely adequate.  Quite frankly, even an uncalibrated RC frequency is adequate.

However, a few projects / products do need the native accuracy of 5% or better.  This is never a problem when we load the calibration value that is programmed in the factory.

My problem arises with the last two batches of chips supplied by Technoshack.  These arrived in sealed bags with Microchip tamper-evident seals.  However, MPALB reports that the chip calibration value is invalid.

I've checked with two different programmers: PICstart Plus and PICkit 3.  Both report the same error.

I spot-checked one chip from each of 30 or so different rails.  All have the same problem.

I'm not sure how to go about dealing with this.  Obviously, I need to get Microchip involved but I'm not sure who to talk with.

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: "Alex, I'll take 'Technology' for $500"; "That's how we avoid buying @#$%"; "Alex, what is an approved vendor list?"

Comment: If you read a blank chip, what value is in memory location 01FF?

Answer (score 2):

They appear to be operating out of a house in Brampton (a heavily ethnically Indian and South Asian area of the GTA). Their US address in Charlotte NC is also a house.

Maybe they are counterfeits or possibly genuine Microchip devices sold at a discount, perhaps into Asian markets, that do not have osccal programmed- check the exact part number on the packaging and chips. I believe Microchip has some reduced cost variants that are sold only in Asia.

Technoshack does not appear to be a franchised distributor. I suggest you contact the vendor (Technoshack) and ask some questions. They may have come by them through some other supplier.

Then, if you don’t get resolution, go to Microchip and determine if the parts are genuine (and are full-spec), and if so if they meet your requirements or if there is a work-around. My recollection is that some parts were being sold as untested or partially tested into Asian markets for use in toys etc, at a fraction of the usual price. Of course the part numbers would be a bit different if Microchip supplied them.

Answer (score 1):

Technoshack in Ontario, Canada appears to be an electronics parts broker.

I cannot find them listed as an authorized Microchip distributor.

Under the best of circumstances a broker finds excess inventory and acts as a middleman to facilitate the purchase of excess inventory for buyers.

Too often they enable entery of gray market parts to the supply chain. These parts could be manufacturer overruns intended for scrap, parametric test failures, pulls from obsolete products or other reasons.

Occasionally the parts are outright fakes, or counterfeits.

I know from articles on the internet that Microchip sells controllers at very low cost, like the PIC12F508, that do not meet specifications. These parts are intended for use in non-critical applications. It would be a simple matter for a die packager to put on an extra shift and run off a few hundred reels of these parts with valid looking markings for sale at fully tested prices.

The brokers I've dealt with do not usually offer value added services like validating the parts they handle are genuine. This means that brokers can be fooled by this kind of operation.

Microchip will be able to tell that the parts you have are genuine. I doubt they have any leverage with Technoshack.

What you do know is that the parts you have are not factory calibrated. As you have tested the parts before your product is assembled and programed you know that your process is not erasing the factory calibration.

The quick(dumb) fix is:

- Use the PICkit3 to regenerate the oscillator calibration.
- The band gap calibration is lost.

The proper solutions is:

- Return the parts to Technoshack for a refund.
- Purchase parts only from an authorized Microchip distributor.

The take away here is unless you really do not need to care do not buy erasable parts from a broker. EVER!

Answer (score 0):

The job title you are looking for is Field Applications Engineer, and you should find one local to your area. They should be able to support you irrespective of which supplier you bought the chips through as long as the chips are genuine.